# Delete repeated icon. files

Tags: windows-10, icons, purge

I have this annoying file called "**icon.**" repeated all over my drive in dozens folders:

[image: [icon. file]]

I wish to purge those files with the command: del /s /q /f /a icon.*

The problem is the last character of this icon file, it is not a simple dot like this one "**.**"

It is kind a special dot, and the Command Prompt is unable to recognize this special character:

[image: error]

Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you using OneDrive? https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_drive-mso_win10-mso_365hp/file-named-icon-shown-in-onedrive-directory/83c2271c-c80e-4f0e-aedd-710c3163dd8d

Comment: Maybe try using [this tool](https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php) to find out what the dot really is, just to get some more info

Comment: If you copy/pasted the name of the file rather than just using a picture of it, maybe someone else could tell you what it is...

Comment: @Meow_ly this tool doesnt work, happens the same thing

Comment: @Tetsujin That is what I get: Icon

Comment: @Meow_ly That is what I get when I try to use the tool: Icon

Comment: Wow! That comes out as `private use area-F00D Unicode U+F00D UTF-8 EF 80 8D` - I have no clue what it is or does, but that's what the data says.